# Remove Record From ObservableCollection Class

Tags: wpf, linq, observablecollection

I am Working on WPF Application and I am getting error means I am not able to Remove Item from the ObservableCollectionClass My Code is given bellow..

it's working but the record is not delete.

```
        SampleDB conn = new SampleDB(Helper.GetPath());

        var Query = from a in conn.UserInfo
                    where a.ID == (int)iSelectedID
                    select new UserDatail { ID = a.ID, Name = a.Name, Address = a.Address, City = a.City, Pin = a.Pin, Phone = a.Phone };

        foreach (var item in Query)
        {
            userDetail.Remove(item);

        }
        dgPorfomance.ItemsSource = userDetail;
        dgPorfomance.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: Not Error, but I am not able to Remove this record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to remove an object from a collection that does not contain this object in the first place.

explanation:

when you do

```
foreach (var item in Query)
    {
        userDetail.Remove(item);
    }
```

you have to be sure that each item in your loop is the same instance than the item contained in the collection. Here, this is not the case: the items may appear to be the same, but they are actually 2 different instances of the same item, as you first get those items from a query and not from your collection

so you should do something like this in this case:

```
foreach (var item in Query)
    {
        foreach (var itemInCollection in userDetail)
        {
             if (itemInCollection.Id == item.Id)
                 userDetail.Remove(itemInCollection );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ObservableCollection` can't find the object you want to remove, because it's different from the one currently in the collection (you just created it with `new`).

You need to override `Equals` in your `UserDetail` class so that two instances can be tested for equality based on your rules:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
    UserDetail other = o as UserDetail;
    if (other != null)
    {
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that when you override `Equals`, you must also override `GetHashCode`:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error might be 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute'.

This is the problem of foreach statement with ienumerable interface to iterate through a collection. To overcome this you can make a shallow copy of the present collection[.ToList() method] and iterate through each.

The solution is:

foreach (var item in Query.ToList())
        {
            userDetail.Remove(item);
        }